# Construction of pre-Brownian motion from Markov transition kernels

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, markov-process

I am reading very nice notes on probability theory by Bruce Driver, but since I didn't have a lecture on the subject I sometimes get confused. In particular, I am confused about the existence of a pre-Brownian motion (process with independent increments where the increments are normally distributed, i.e. a Brownian motion but not necessarily continuous). [Corollary 22.27](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Ebdriver/Cornell%20Summer%20Notes%202010/Lecture_Notes/Probability%20Tools%20with%20Examples.pdf#page=255) states the existence of pre-B motion and is based on [exercise 17.8](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Ebdriver/Cornell%20Summer%20Notes%202010/Lecture_Notes/Probability%20Tools%20with%20Examples.pdf#page=255) (which says that if the pre-B motion would exist it would have some properties) and [Theorem 17.11](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Ebdriver/Cornell%20Summer%20Notes%202010/Lecture_Notes/Probability%20Tools%20with%20Examples.pdf#page=250) which states that given Markov transition kernels we can construct a Markov process with those kernels. However, I am having a hard time piecing this together.

Answer (score 1):

What you call 'pre-Brownian motion' is just the usual Brownian motion, but considered only on events in the cylindrical sigma algebra. The cylindrical sigma algebra is a 'very small' sigma algebra generated by finite dimensional random variables of the form $f(B_{t_1},...,B_{t_n})$; for instance supremums of the process do not belong to it: the supremum of 'pre-Brownian motion' simply does not make direct sense.

The reason some authors consider it nonetheless is because of the Kolmogorov extension theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem, which states that basically any (in particular Markov) family of consistent (in terms of marginalization; e.g. for Markov it's just the semi-group property of probability transitions) finite dimensional distributions generates a well-defined process distribution on the cylindrical sigma algebra. What you seem to struggle with is the direct application of this Kolmogorov extension theorem to the case of the heat kernel.

Now note that this process distribution may be a.s. continuous in some sense, it's just that this statement does not make sense on this restrictive cylindrical sigma algebra. So the point is not that 'pre-Brownian motion' is "not necessarily continuous", the point is that "continuity does not make sense" for pre-Brownian motion.

The magic trick, which is missing in the refs you are mentioning is the Kolmogorov continuity theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem
which ensures that you can uniquely 'lift' your 'pre-Brownian motion' to a proper stochastic process seen as a random variable in the Polish space of continuous paths (endowed with the uniform norm). By doing so, you considerably extend the sigma algebra on which your process is defined: any path functional which is Borel measurable for continuous trajectories will work. Kolmogorov continuity theorem exactly tells you that there is a unique natural way to do that from the cylindrical sigma aglebra.

Finally, note that the Kolmogorov extension theorem is very general, but very abstract, and requires the underlying probability space to be 'large' (not just (0,1) with Uniform). From the perspective of constructive mathematics, mathematical physics, or simulation, it is not very satisfactory. Some authors try to avoid it. All basic cadlag random processes can be constructed without it, see for instance Levy's construction of Brownian motion.

Finally, I don't think that considering Kolmogorov extension (abstract existence) without Kolomogorov continuity (continuous version + uniqueness) is insightful. Both are better, and nicer, together.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I guess what is still not clear to me is why if we can construct a process with the heat kernels does it satisfy the property that $X_t-X_s\overset{d}{=}N(0,t-s)$ and has independent increments. I know that If $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is the process constructed with the heat Markov kernels, we must have $law(X_s,X_t)(dx,dy)=q_{s-0}(dx)q_{t-s}(x,dy)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{1}{2s}|x|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(t-s)}|y-x|^2}dxdy$ but how to deduce from this that the distribution of $X_t-X_s$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$? and the independent increments?

Comment: OK this is much easier. Just forget about BM, and consider it as an exercise on distributions in $\mathbb R ^2$. i) Your Q is very simple: do see it probably you need to have a look at changes of variables in $\mathbb R ^2$: here set $x:=x, z:= y-x$, obviously $dx dy = dx dz$ and you just get the formula for two independent Gaussian distributions.

Comment: ii) It the present case (Gaussian distributions), have a look at a basic course on Gaussian vectors + linear algebra. Any linear transformation preserves the Gaussianity of distributions, and in that context computations with finite dimensional distributions of Gaussian processes becomes conceptually simple.

Comment: i)I tried to follow your guidlines but there must be something I am doing wrong. If I do the change of variable I get $law(X_s,X_t)(dx,dz)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{1}{2s}|x|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t-s}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(t-s)}|z|}$ which is a Gaussian random vector with variance matrix $C=\begin{bmatrix}s&0\\0&t-s\end{bmatrix}$ and since my linear transformation is $(X_s,X_t)\mapsto (X_t-X_s)$ its matrix is $A=[-1,1]$ and so $A\begin{bmatrix}X_s\\X_t\end{bmatrix}$ will be Gaussian with variance $ACA^T=s+t-s =t$ but I should get $t-s$ for the new variance since I want $\mathcal{N}(0, t-s)$ no?

Comment: After the change of variable what you get is the pdf of $(X_s,X_t-X_s)$ instead of $(X_s,X_t)$ written using $(x,z)$ variables, since the pdf of $(X_s,X_t)$ was written using $(x,y)$ variables.

Comment: Okay, I tried to summarize everything in an answer, of course I will give you the bounty. Let me know what you think

Comment: I think this is correct. Note that you can alternatively prove things more concisely by proving the independence between $X_s$ and $X_t - X_s$ at the same time that you compute the distribution of $X_t-X_s$. By the Markov property, all other statements about independence will follow.

Comment: When you say "it's just that this statement does not make sense on this restrictive cylindrical sigma algebra", it is because $\{\omega:t\mapsto X_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous}\}$ is not measurable with respect to the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra? Could you just expand a bit on the lift via Kolmogorov's continuity theorem as in the wikipedia article they actually don't even talk about $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can construct measurable events to express continuity, but you have to restrict the time index $t$ in a countable subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The 'lift' is a term I use informally, but which is not standard. The standard term is 'modification'. But in fact, on the cylindrical sigma algebra, 'modification' is the same thing as 'almost surely equal', so that you can make sense of the idea that 'random process defined on the cylindrical sigma' or 'random process up to modification' are equivalent concepts. Now in Kolmogorov's continuity theorem it is stated that 'there exists a modification' which if you start from the cylindrical sigma algebra just means 'extension on the Borel sigma algebra generated by continuous paths'.

Comment: Finally note that uniqueness of the 'lift' comes from the fact that two continuous processes that have the same distribution on a countable dense subset of the time index have necessarily the same overall distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try to answer my question, maybe I can get some feedbacks.
Exercise 17.8 says that the heat kernels satisfy the Chapman-Kolmogorovs equation and theorem 17.11 thus says that we can construct a Markov process with these as transition kernels.

What is left to show is that if we have constructed a Markov process $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ with the heat kernels as its transition kernels, this process has increments $X_t-X_s\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$ and if $t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n$ we have $X_{t_2}-X_{t_1},X_{t_3}-X_{t_2},\ldots,X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}$ are independent increments. First note that by theorem 17.10 we have

$$law(_,_)(,)=_{−0}(0,)_{−}(,)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^{−\frac{1}{2 }^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(−)}}^{−\frac{1}{2(−)}(−)^2}.$$ Using the change of variable formula we have
\begin{align}
P(X_t-X_s\in A)
=&E[1_A(X_t-X_s)]\\
=&\int 1_A(y-x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi s}}e^{−\frac{1}{2 s}^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{−\frac{1}{2(t−s)}(y−x)^2}dxdy\\
=&\int 1_A(z)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{−\frac{1}{2 s}^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{−\frac{1}{2(t−s)}z^2}dxdz\\
=&\int 1_A(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{−\frac{1}{2(t−s)}z^2}dz\\
=&E[1_A(Z)]
\end{align}

where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$. We used the change of variable $x=x$, $z=y-x$ for which the jacobian is $1$ and the fact that $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^{−\frac{1}{2 }^2}dx=1$.

For the independence I just show it for $t_1<t_2<t_3$ as the general case is similar :

\begin{align}
law(X_1,X_2,X_3)(dx_1,dx_2,dx_3)&=q_{t_1-0}(0,dx_1)q_{t_2-t_1}(x_1,dx_2)q_{t_3-t_2}(x_2,dx_3)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_1}}e^{-\frac{x_1}{2t_1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{x_2-x_1}{2(t_2-t_1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{x_3-x_2}{2(t_2-t_1)}}
\end{align}

Again by the change of variable formula :
\begin{align}
&P((X_2-X_1,X_3-X_2)\in A)\\=&E[1_A(X_2-X_1,X_3-X_2)]\\
=&\int 1_A(x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_1}}e^{-\frac{x_1}{2t_1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{x_2-x_1}{2(t_2-t_1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{x_3-x_2}{2(t_2-t_1)}}dx_1dx_2dx_3\\
=&\int 1_A(u_2,u_3)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_1}}e^{-\frac{u_1}{2t_1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{u_2}{2(t_2-t_1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{u_3}{2(t_2-t_1)}}du_1du_2du_3\\
=&\int 1_A(u_2,u_3)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{u_2}{2(t_2-t_1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{u_3}{2(t_2-t_1)}}du_2du_3\\
=&E[1_A(Z_1,Z_2)]
\end{align}
where $(Z_1,Z_2)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\begin{bmatrix}t_2-t_1&0\\0&t_3-t_2\end{bmatrix})$ in particular the components are independent. We have used the change of variable $x_1=u_1, x_2-x_1=u_2,\ldots x_n-x_{n-1}=u_n$ which has jacobian $1$.